# Avoid warning this type of file can harm your computer on download

Tags: javascript, html, download

I want to create a download link and attach javascript code to track GA events or open a new page for instance.
Let's consider using Chrome ( e.g. in IE behavior is the same ).
Everything works fine, download starts normally:

`<a class="download-link" href="XXX.application">Click to Download</a>`

Attaching an event to a link and opening new window using `window.open` will open a window in new tab and pop up a warning whether I want to accept a file:

`This type of file can harm your computer....`

After opening a generic link in a new tab/window without any javascript will cause same warning:

`<a class="download-link" href="XXX.application" target="_blank">Click to Download</a>`

Same happens if I use javascript `window.location`:

```
$('.download-link').click(function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      window.location.href = 'XXX.application';
      return false;
});
```

The question is simple, why am I experiencing such weird behavior? How I can start download without warning and redirect to a different page or run code before link is followed?

Comment: The warning is an OS behavior which you cannot bypass. Because application are exhaustible, so are viruses that's why the warning comes, to inform the user be careful before downloading and running.

Comment: @Godinall As I said following a link in a browser without opening it in a new window, won't trigger any warning.

Comment: not always the case. Like I said, it is an OS/Browser behavior, totally out of your control with code. When following in the same page, it meets the "same-origin" rule which will make browser believe it is safe and it is a user action, not a harmful script run on the page.